# angularjs $location.path.replace not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm building a website, which is a single page website with multiple views. I'm using angularJS to handle the back-end communication.

Right now I have a menu-bar on top, and if I click it the old page is supposed to slide to the left, fade out, the view is changed, the view goes to the right and slides in while fading in. While this is al working perfectly, for some reason the path changing won't work. My code:

(part of MainController.js)

```
$scope.goToPage = function(pageId){
        if(!$scope.animatingMainContent){
            $scope.animatingMainContent = true;
            $("#viewTitle").css({opacity: 1});
            $("#viewTitle").animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 500, queue: false});
            $("#viewContainer").animate({left: "-200px", opacity: 0.1}, {duration: 500, complete: function(){
                $location.path("/"+pageId).replace();
                console.log($location.url());
                $("#viewContainer").css("left", "200px");
                $("#viewTitle").animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 500, queue: false});
                $("#viewTitle").html($scope.pageTitles[pageId]);
                $("#viewContainer").animate({left: 0,opacity: 1}, {duration: 500, complete: function(){
                    $scope.animatingMainContent = false;
                    $location.path("/"+pageId).replace();
                }});
            }});
        }
    }
```

(the menubar)

```
<strong class="ribbon-content">
    <a ng-click="goToPage('about');">About Me</a> | <a ng-click="goToPage('portfolio');">Portfolio</a> | <a ng-click="goToPage('contact');">Contact</a>
</strong>
```

So, thing is, that when I go to a page, it gets the previous path. You start on "About Me". Say that I were to click "Portfolio", "Contact", "About Me", I would see: About Me, Portfolio. Contact, when the view loads. But the console would say:

```
"/portfolio"
"/contact"
"/about"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$location.path(...).replace()` is within jQuery event handlers (animation finished function). You need to call `$scope.$apply()` for Angular to get the change.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I completely forgot about that. I remembered having the problem earlier, but I forgot that I used $scope.$apply to solve it!